# Facebook Users logging fine but not showing up in api requests

Tags: javascript, facebook, parse-platform

I have an Android and Web app that uses the Parse backend with FB login. I just created the Web version and I'm having an issue with my users that log in through web. They are being saved to the backend just fine along with their FB info, but for some reason, when I make a me/friends api request, I cannot find any of my friends that have logged in through my website (anyone that logged in through the Android app shows up just fine). This leads me to believe that even though the Parse login worked fine, there is probably an issue with FB login. My code is exactly as the parse docs describe:

```
            Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn(null, {
              success: function(user) {
                if (!user.existed()) {

                    FB.api('/me', function(response) {

                        var currentUser = Parse.User.current();

                        if (currentUser) {
                        currentUser.set("fbName", response.name);
                        currentUser.set("facebookId", response.id);
                        currentUser.save();
                        window.location = "index.html";
                        } else {
                        alert("Login Did Not Work!");
                        }


                            });
                } else {

                    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                        Parse.User.current().set("fbName", response.name);
                        Parse.User.current().set("facebookId", response.id);
                        Parse.User.current().save();
                        window.location = "index.html";
                            });
                }
              },
              error: function(user, error) {
                alert("User cancelled the Facebook login or did not fully authorize.");
              }
            });
```

Is there something else I should be doing here?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is having the same problem, I simply forgot to include the user_friends permission (or any permission for that matter, but user_friends is what I wanted).